# Workcentre 5325 Как безболезненно очистить только очередь работ?

Tags: принтер

Очередь работ защищенной печати на общем Хероксе 5325 забита настолько, что к ней он обращается с завидным терпением. Милые дамы оправляют на печать годами и там лежит кладбище лучших сочинений сотрудников. Но духи прошлого одолевают разум трудяги 5325, я так думаю, заставляют его вспомнить каждую рукопись что видели его электрические мозги. Как избавить беднягу от груза ответственности?

Answer (score 0):

В настройках от имени админа или веб-интерфейсе есть таймаут хранения работ. Как раз для данной ситуации.